# Why do copy and paste in windows change symbols in the long text?

Tags: windows, copy, copy-paste, paste

Let me write a random sequence for example:

`TEST1_TEST2_TEST3_TEST4_TEST5_TEST6_TEST7`

Now If I try to copy it and paste back this results in:

`TESdAmVfGT1K8MnsmuYQby2wJibmeiHnQwVHTMy37cr8fluRvLc5ket1J2WMuE8JJeN5WsA1v8DxhXBezXy1STMy3XuRvLxEXuRvLxE`

and if i paste again:

`TESdAmVfGT1K8MnsmuYQby2wJibmeiHnQwVHTMy37cr8fluRvLc5ket1J2WMuE8JJeN5WsA1v8DxhXBezXy1SdAmVfGT1K8MnsmuYQby2wJibmeiHnQwVHDxhXBezXy1SdAmVfGT1K8MnsmuYQby2wJibmeiHnQwVHLsoDBC2dQBZXCXd6nk1g1MRU4nUMXAHNFBEJhkTZV9HdaL4gfuNBxLPc3BeMkLGaPbF5vWtANQuhojvBrujRSdAmVfGT1K8MnsmuYQby2wJibmeiHnQwVHlVl`

If I do it with the smaller sequence it works fine. I.e I can copy `TEST1_TEST2_TEST3_TEST4_TEST5_TEST6` (first letters of the sequence above), but if I add 1 more letter I can't.

I can't find a person who could reproduce the problem yet.
I have Windows 10 Pro, though my friend with the same Windows can't reproduce the problem.

How could this happen? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a malware... just try with Malwarebytes...

Comment: Thank you so much! i thinked the problem was a coding problem